# Average of Score based on Distinct ID

Tags: powerbi, dax

I have a table where a Student's GPA shows up in multiple rows due to grades received in different subjects. I am trying to calculate the Average GPA in Power BI using DAX, I am still a beginner when it comes to DAX calculations. I am providing a table below along with my formula. Can someone please tell me what am I doing wrong here?

> Average(values(tbl[GPA]),DistinctCount(tbl1[ID])))

I am attaching a sample here below:
[image]

Comment: To increase chances of receiving an answer, I suggest you to adopt the standard template: 1) Context, 2) Problem, 3) Example with a table, 4) Expected results in the table of (3) Example.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of Average, use AverageX as below

`AVERAGEX(VALUES(tbl1[ID]), CALCULATE(AVERAGE(tbl1[GPA])))`

[image]

Answer (score 1):

- You can use the "Average" option as per the screenshot.
- Or just create a measure = Average(tbl[GPA]) and use it.

[image]

Comment: I know about that however, if you look at the data that I have provided above you can see that an ID gets listed with the same GPA a couple number of times and I only want to count it once.